# scandir(/var/app/current/protected/modules): Failed to open directory: No such file or directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yii2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have tried to host humhub which is an yii2 open source social media on aws elastic beanstalk but when I open the site I get an error exception

Can anyone tell me how to fix it please?

This is the error

PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException

scandir(/var/app/current/protected/modules): Failed to open directory: No such file or directory

1. in /var/app/current/protected/humhub/components/bootstrap/ModuleAutoLoader.php at line 50
2. yii\base\ErrorHandler::handleError(2, 'scandir(/var/app/current/protect...', '/var/app/current/protected/humhu...', 50)
3. in /var/app/current/protected/humhub/components/bootstrap/ModuleAutoLoader.php at line 50 – scandir('/var/app/current/protected/modul...')
4. in /var/app/current/protected/humhub/components/bootstrap/ModuleAutoLoader.php at line 32 – humhub\components\bootstrap\ModuleAutoLoader::locateModules()
5. in /var/app/current/protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php at line 327 – humhub\components\bootstrap\ModuleAutoLoader::bootstrap(humhub\components\Application)
6. in /var/app/current/protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php at line 69 – yii\base\Application::bootstrap()
7. in /var/app/current/protected/humhub/components/Application.php at line 46 – yii\web\Application::bootstrap()
8. in /var/app/current/protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php at line 273 – humhub\components\Application::bootstrap()
9. in /var/app/current/protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php at line 109 – yii\base\Application::init()
10. in /var/app/current/protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php at line 206 – yii\base\BaseObject::__construct(['name' => 'HumHub', 'version' => '1.5.1', 'bootstrap' => ['log', 'humhub\components\bootstrap\Modu...', 'queue', 'humhub\modules\ui\view\bootstrap...', ...], 'sourceLanguage' => 'en', ...])
11. in /var/app/current/index.php at line 25 – yii\base\Application::__construct(['name' => 'HumHub', 'version' => '1.5.1', 'bootstrap' => ['log', 'humhub\components\bootstrap\Modu...', 'queue', 'humhub\modules\ui\view\bootstrap...', ...], 'sourceLanguage' => 'en', ...])

Comment: It isn't a good idea to ask others to open an url to see the error. Copy and paste the error in your question. If there is visual information (and not only text), insert a screenshot

Comment: Thanx I will edit it

Comment: does protected/modules even exist?

Comment: Yes, it does. I even run it using xammp on my PC an it run just fine.

Comment: @Chux I think it is permission error but I don't know how to solve it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Ahmed what are the folder permissions? Which user is running the apache service?